# Как я могу отсканировать текст, введенный пользователем, имеющий в себе "\n" в java

Tags: java, scanner

Пишу небольшой консольный анализатор текста. Когда пользователь вводит текст, имеющий перенос строки, происходит ошибка (в переменную входит только первая строка, которая была до переноса).

Все мои попытки по типу этой:

```
System.out.println("enter your text");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String message = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\n", " ");
```

были тщетны. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Тщетны. Извините, не удержался

Comment: А как вы собираетесь отличать, что пользователь закончил вводить текст? Двумя пустыми строками `\n\n`?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, чтение текста лучше производить в цикле:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    message = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: это больше комментарий, чем ответ

Comment: согласен, но не могу писать комментарии пока)

Answer (score 0):

Можно изменить делимитер в сканере и вычитывать строки, используя `Scanner::next`.

Например, установив в качестве делимитера двойной перевод строки, можно вычитывать текст, содержащий `\n`:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n\n");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    String line = sc.next();
    list.add(line);
    if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
        break;
    }
}

list.stream().map(s -> "[" + s + "]").forEach(System.out::println);
```

Пример ввода-вывода:

```
sss
www
ddd

111
222

q
```

Вывод списка, строки содержат `\n`

```
[sss
www
ddd]
[111
222]
[q]
```